# Selenium Python Microsoft Edge Testing

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am doing automated tests on MS Edge, I am unable to do send keys to the text field of my local website. The same code runs perfect for chrome even in Windows 10.

I am using Python 2.7 and a proper version of MicrosoftWebDriver.

```
class login(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge()
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://localhost/project/interio/interio/")
     #def test_search_in_python_org(self):

    def test_Login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        #def txt():
        #return ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(5)
        loginfinal = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='AdminLogInFinal.php']") #for login
    loginfinal.click()
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_name('user')
    ID=Login_name.send_keys('09')
    test6 = Login_name.get_attribute('value')#.encode('utf-8')
    print test6
    Login_password= driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
    #Login_password.send_keys('se')
    test7 = Login_password.get_attribute('value')#.encode('utf-8')
    print test7
        log=driver.find_element_by_class_name("Button").click()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**ERROR**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Errorstackoverflow.py", line 30, in test_Login
    Login_name= driver.find_element_by_name('user')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 365, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element

Comment: I think you forgot to include your code.

Comment: can you also add the exception you are getting? stack trace?

Comment: Please find the error pasted above

Comment: No body here to answer me?

Comment: Based on your error message, webdriver is not finding the element to send_keys to.